# Cannot start apache on xampp 2.4

Tags: apache

I am running xampp normal but when I stop it and restart the following error occurred:`Attempting to start Apache service...`

I've tried changing the port in `httpd.conf` from 80 to 3030 and `httpd-ssl.conf` from 443 to 4499 but no result.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Infact Skype blocks the Apache port. So terminate it or change the port like the image I sent to you and try again.I think Your Problem will be solved

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, you can check with `netstat -a -n -o` if ports 80 and 443 are already in use. There is more than one program known for blocking the needed ports. If you see a process blocking port 80 or 443 (lets say PID 8256), you can use `tasklist /fi "PID eq 8256"` to find out which process you need to kill.

Comment: thanks for answer. The reason is the file `httpd-vhost.conf` wrong format